# Loop over specified rows of a csv file using Python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am using the package csv in python 2.7

```
import csv    
f=open('Path\Top.csv')


csv_f = csv.reader(f)
counter = 0
for row in csv_f:
    if counter ==0 :
        next
    # Do some more stuff
    counter += 1
```

The first row contains headers and i don't wish to include it in the loop. I am trying the above scheme to omit the first row from analysis.

Is there an elegant way of accomplishing the same, the above scheme doesn't work.

Also, how do I iterate from some row i to row j without having to start from first row every time.The file is big and it wastes time to start from 1st row every single time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next)  is a function, not a control flow statement.  Use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) instead to get the behavior you want.  You'll also need to increment in the `if` block since `continue` will skip the rest of the `for` loop iteration.

```
if counter == 0:
    counter += 1
    continue
```

Alternatively, a cleaner approach (assuming you don't need `counter`) would be to use `next` to skip the first row before you get to the `for` loop.  This also demonstrates the correct usage of `next`.  In this example, I'm ignoring the return value of `next(csv_f)` but it's worth noting that it will contain the CSV header in case you wanted to do something with that before looping over the rows.

```
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f) # Skip header
for row in csv_f:
    # Do some more stuff
    print row
```

If you do need `counter`, a more Pythonic way of doing things would be to use built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

```
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for counter, row in enumerate(csv_f):
    if counter == 0:
        continue
    # Do some more stuff
    print row
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about continue and next. Is there any way to iterate over custom row numbers, say from row i to row j besides starting from first row every single time?

Comment: @perpetual_wheel Take a look at `itertools.islice` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).  This will let you iterate over a specified start and stop interval.